# Python applying logical_xor function on two gif images returns the error ValueError: image has wrong mode

Tags: python, encryption, python-imaging-library, xor

I have two gif images and I need to do logical_xor on them from [PIL](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/ImageChops.py) library
This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
```

image = Image.open("image.gif")
key = Image.open("key.gif")

test = image.mode == key.mode

print(test)

def logical_xor(image1, image2):
    """Logical XOR between two images.
        .. code-block:: python
        out = ((bool(image1) != bool(image2)) % MAX)
       :rtype: :py:class:`~PIL.Image.Image`
       """

```
   image1.load()
   image2.load()
   return image1._new(image1.im.chop_xor(image2.im))

secret = logical_xor(image, key)
```

I am getting this error:

> `True
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/negut_000/OneDrive/Scoala/Crypto/Image Encrypt Decrypt OTP/Encrypt.py", line 24, in <module>
>     secret = logical_xor(image, key)
>   File "C:/Users/negut_000/OneDrive/Scoala/Crypto/Image Encrypt Decrypt OTP/Encrypt.py", line 21, in logical_xor
>     return image1._new(image1.im.chop_xor(image2.im))
> ValueError: image has wrong mode
>
> Process finished with exit code 1`

It seems that the images have the same mode so I don't understand the problem.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Using instead of

```
   image = Image.open("image.gif")
   key = Image.open("key.gif")
```

This code

```
image = Image.open("image.gif", mode='r').convert("1")
key = Image.open("key.gif", mode='r').convert("1")
```